# How do I access a list and items from another class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a list and then add/read items from the list using python and tkinter.

I need to create a blank list, and add things too it, and then also be able to clear the entry from the widget created within a function in another class. I have been trying everything and cannot figure out how to access the widgets/list like I need to.

The error i keep getting is AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'data'

Any help is appreciated.

```
from tkinter import font as tkfont

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        self.frames["StartPage"] = StartPage(parent=container, controller=self)

        self.frames["StartPage"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.grid(columnspan=5, rowspan=5)

        self.start = tk.Button(self, text='Start', command=lambda: self.start_frame())
        self.start.pack(side='top')


    def start_frame(self):
        data = []
        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        frame.pack(side='top', fill='both')

        entry = tk.Text(frame)
        entry.bind('<Return>', lambda event: stored_functions.print_date(self, entry=entry.get('1.0', 'end-1c')))
        entry.pack(side='top')



class stored_functions():
    def print_date(self, entry):
        StartPage.start_frame.entry.delete('1.0', tk.END)
        all_entries = StartPage.start_frame.data
        print('The last entry was {} \n\n Here is all the entries: {}'.format(entry, all_entries))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific as to what the error is? You said you tried everything: what did you try, and what went wrong with those attempts? *How* do you need to access the widgets/list? Being more specific in your question helps us better understand, so that we can help you out.

Comment: @SamMatzko I keep getting the error saying AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: Thank you. You should probably put this in your question, so that other users know what the error was without reading the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get variables from a class, you need to initialize it first. In the line `StartPage.start_frame.entry.delete('1.0', tk.END)`, you try to access a variable from the `StartPage` class itself, not an *instance* of the class. You also try to access the `start_frame` method's variable (`start_frame.entry`), without calling the method.

When you bind the entry in the line `entry.bind('<Return>', lambda event: stored_functions.print_date(self, entry=entry.get('1.0', 'end-1c')))`, you make a similar mistake in using `stored_functions.print_date(...` instead of `stored_functions().print_date(...` (notice the parentheses).

When you need to access a variable outside of a method, it is good practice to create the variable with `self.` at the beginning. This makes it so that the variable can be accessed throughout the class, and by outside code using an instance of the class. Here is the modified code, with added and edited lines marked accordingly:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font as tkfont

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        self.frames["StartPage"] = StartPage(parent=container, controller=self)

        self.frames["StartPage"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.grid(columnspan=5, rowspan=5)

        self.start = tk.Button(self, text='Start', command=lambda: self.start_frame())
        self.start.pack(side='top')


    def start_frame(self):
        self.data = []
        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        frame.pack(side='top', fill='both')

        self.entry = tk.Text(frame) ### EDITED LINE
        self.entry.bind('<Return>', lambda event: stored_functions().print_date(self, entry=self.entry.get('1.0', 'end-1c'))) ### EDITED LINE
        self.entry.pack(side='top') ### EDITED LINE



class stored_functions():
    def print_date(self, start_page, entry): ### EDITED LINE
        start_page.entry.delete('1.0', tk.END) ### EDITED LINE
        all_entries = start_page.data ### EDITED LINE
        print('The last entry was {} \n\n Here is all the entries: {}'.format(entry, all_entries))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

I changed the line where the entry is bound so that when `"<Enter>"` is pressed, it passes the instance of `StartPage` and the entry's text as arguments to `stored_functions.print_date()`.

Notice that when the entry is created in `StartPage.start_frame()`, it is called `self.entry`, not simply `entry`. Also note that `stored_functions.print_date()` uses `start_page.entry` instead of `StartPage.start_frame.entry`, and `start_page.data` instead of `StartPage.start_frame.data`. This is because `start_page` is referencing an *instance* of the `StartPage` class, not the class itself.

Comment: This is so helpful. Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me. So adding self. to the beginning of anything created within the class makes it an instance of the class, and callable from outside the class?  I am understanding that now, thank you so much. I do not really understand what you mean by trying to access a variable without calling the method (1st paragraph). I do not think i understand what a "method" is because looking over this code, all the "code" has been called before it gets there.

Comment: A "method" is just a function inside a class that has `self` as an argument in it's `def` statement. So `def something(self):` inside a class would be a method, while `def something():` inside a class, or `def something(self):` outside a class, would not be a method.

Comment: What I meant by "trying to access a variable without calling the method": when a variable is created inside a method (or a function), it *only* exists if the method (or function) is called. `entry` is defined inside the `start_frame` method, so `entry` *only* exists if `start_frame` is called. However, you try to access `start_frame.entry` *without* calling `start_frame`, so `entry` does not exist.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Sorry I forgot to do that yesterday.  So I have been playing around with stuff using your response and using the information provided I have saved so much time and frustration, but can't seem to wrap my head around it. For the bind lambda command, you added () after the stored function class call, and somehow that ends up passing the entire frame as a variable you can then call. Could you explain how just adding () is able to pass the entire class?

Comment: As I explained above, all methods (functions in a class) have an argument called `self`, which, *when* the class is initialized, enables the method to use the class' variables when it is called. However, when the class is *not* initialized, nothing gets passed to the `self` argument of the method  when it is called. So, when you give the instance of `StartPage` to `stored_functions.print_date()`, it is put in the `self` argument of `print_date()`, instead of the `start_page` argument, simply because nothing *was* put in the `self` argument.

Comment: continued... So, using `stored_functions().print_date(..` *initializes* the class, so that `print_date()` gets the `self` agrument. There are probably lots of questions on SO, and tutorials, Wikipedia pages, etc. online that can explain this better than I can (and without a length limit :-) ). It's okay if you can't quite wrap your head around this yet; you *will* understand. Just keep learning and stay curious!

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you again for explaining all this to me. I have another follow-up question if you don't mind. Lets say instead of printing that statement, i made it a label and placed it on the screen: label=tk.Label(start_page.frame, text=...etc) then I place it. Now later in the program, I want to do something with that label I created. I have not added a self. to it, so when I try and reference that object, I keep getting 'frame' object has no attribute 'label'.

Comment: Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, yes, you can put `self.` in front of a label too. You can put `self.` in front of any variable you want to access at all later in the program. Sorry if I misunderstood the question, let me know if I did!